# Regex that gets a sentence containing a name

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am creating regexes that get the whole sentence if a piece of specific information exists. Right now I am working on my name regex, so if there is any composed name (example: "Jorge Martel", "Jorge Martel del Arnold Albuquerque") the regex should get the whole sentence that has the name.

**If I have these two sentences:**

(1) - "A hardworking guy is working at the supermarket. They call him Jorge Horizon, but that's not his real name."

(2) - "He has an identity document that contains the name, Jorge Martel Arnold."

**The regex should return these two results from the sentences above:**

(1) - "They call him Jorge Horizon, but that's not his real name."

(2) - "He has an identity document that contains the name, Jorge Martel Arnold."

This is my regex:

```
(?:(?(?<=[\.!?]\s([A-Z]))(.+?[^.])|))?((?:(?:[A-Z][A-zÀ-ÿ']+\s(?:(?:(?:[A-zÀ-ÿ']{1,3}\s)?(?:[A-ZÀ-Ÿ][A-zÀ-ÿ']*\s?))+))\b)(.+?[\.!?](?:\s|\n|\Z)))
```

Basically, it verifies if there is a dot, exclamation, or interrogation symbol with a blank space and an upper case character and tells the regex that everything must be select, else it should get all the sentence.

My else case (|) right now is empty, because using (.+?) avoids my first condition...

**Regex without the else case:**

[image: Validates until the dot, but doesn't get the second sentence]

Validates until the dot, but doesn't get the second sentence.

**Regex with the else case:**

[image: Validates the whole sentence, but doesn't get the first sentence]

Validates the second sentence, but overrides the first condition that appears in the first sentence.

I expect my regex to return correctly the sentences:

- "They call him Jorge Horizon, but that's not his real name."
- "He has an identity document that contains the name, Jorge Martel Arnold."

I have also created a text to validate the regex operations as I will be using it a lot in texts. I added a lot of conditions in this text, which will probably appear in my daily work.

Check my regex, sentence, and text [here](https://regex101.com/r/jEc8h9/5):

Does anyone know what should I change in my regex? I have tried many variations and still cannot find the solution.

P.S.: I intend to use it in my python code, but I need to fix it with the regex and not with the python code.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches English letters and these characters `[`, `]`, `^`, `_`, backslash and backtick. Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: You don't allow names with a single character. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Toto actually I use [A-Z\u00C0-\u00DC] and [A-Z\u00C0-\u00DC][A-zÀ-ÿ'], to validate names with accentuation and different characters, I just didn't add it in this question because it can break in some regex flavors. So I only used the default characters validation in the question.

Comment: @Toto indeed I don't allow names, I will verify if I can create something that allows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((?:^|(?:[^\.!?]*))[^\.!?\n]*(?:(?:[A-ZÀ-Ÿ][A-zÀ-ÿ']+\s?){2,}[^\.!?]*[\.!?]))
```

It will capture sentences where name has at least two words, e.g. `His name is John Smith.`

It won't capture sentences like: `John went to a concert.`

Comment: I tried it with a text that I created in my regex link, and it will get the whole text. If you may have a look at my regex (updated link), it contains many conditions that I will be using in my task. I will try to see what is not right in your regex example after seeing the other answers. :)

Comment: @Codewraith I edited the regex in my answer, try now.

Comment: I have tried the regex but when I have a word that has dots like the IP 000.000.000.000.000, it will select everything until the first dot and will stop there, the validation to solve that would be having a dot, blank space and upper case to validate middle sentences or just an upper case when it is the first sentence of a text. For some reason your regex is also considering \n, so a new line is also considered which should not be the case.

Comment: @Codewraith well I think you have a good basis, you can build up on that

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
[\w\ \,\']+\.\ ?([\w\ \,\']+\.)|^([\w\ \,\']+\.)$
```

prints $1$2. I.e if group one is empty it prints blank since there is no match, then will print group 2. Visa versa, it prints group 1 when group 2 is not there.

[\w\ ,']+.\ ?([\w\ ,']+.) - as matching anything with XXX. XXX.

then

^([\w\ ,']+.)$ - must start end with only 1 sentence.

Though honestly this can easily be done with a Tokenizer of (.) that check length of 1 or 2. It' really like using a sledgehammer to hammer a nail.

Comment: Even though it uses groups for the sentences it doesn't work as expected when a text appears, I added a text in my regex link if you may want to check. I have tried it with your regex but sometimes it gets it right and others it simply doesn't. What would be the idea of the tokenizer of (.)? Because if you see in the text (updated regex link) I might have some information that has dots in the middle of the text, the IP for example, would it work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Matching names can be a very hard job using a regex, but if you want to match at least 2 consecutive uppercase words using the specified ranges.

Assuming the names start with an uppercase char A-Z (else you can extend that character class as well with the allowed chars or if supported use `\p{Lu}` to match an uppercase char that has a lowercase variant):

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z][A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]*(?:\s+[a-zÀ-ÿ,]+)*\s+[A-Z][a-zÀ-ÿ]*\s+[A-Z][a-zÀ-ÿ,]*.*?[.!?](?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[A-Z][A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z optionally followed by matching the defined ranges
- `(?:\s+[a-zÀ-ÿ,]*)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and 1 or more of the ranges
- `\s+[A-Z][a-zÀ-ÿ]*\s+[A-Z][a-zÀ-ÿ,]*` Match 2 times whitespace chars followed by an uppercase A-Z and optional chars defined in the character class
- `.*?[.!?]` Match as least as possible chars followed by one of `.` `!` or `?`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO1STC/1)

Comment: It almost did the trick, but when I tried the regex in a more complex structure it didn't work in all cases. I added a text in my regex (to validate the results), I tested it with your regex, and sometimes the validation doesn't work. If you could have a look I would appreciate it. After I try the other answers, I will come back to yours to try to make it work.

Comment: @Codewraith You could extend the character classes also matching digits and dots for example https://regex101.com/r/ysDRD2/1 and if there can be a single lowercase word between the uppercase words you could make that optional.

Comment: Nice, that really helps a lot! Do you know why it isn't matching "Not many years later, Jorge del Arnold got tired from work and built his supermarket." and matching "Those were hairy days." ? I will have a look if I can find out why but is quite strange this behaviour.

Comment: @Codewraith It does not match the first sentence as there is a lowercase word between the 2 uppercase words. It does match the second one as the character class now matches a dot, and will overmatch it to match the 2 uppercased words.

Comment: Yeah, I found the problem in the first one, and I'm solving it now, after that I will verify the second problem. Thanks. As soon I fix it I will send it here.

Comment: I can't see why you used the "(?<!\S)" because it doesn't change anything in the text. About the validation starting with the upper case, unfortunately, doesn't work properly because it breaks in many cases and sentences like "Jorge Martel is working at CIA" are not caught. The thing is I need to verify if there is a name in the string and it must be compound ("Jorge Martel" or "Jorge del Martel" or "Jorge Martel del Garcia" ). The starting validation that verifies if there is any upper case between will always break the regex.

Comment: This part `(?<!\S)` prevents match a non whitespace char before the uppercase char. So it will not match `.Test`

Comment: Ok, understood. This "\*.\*?" is also a problem because it caught the sentence below for example "Jorge Martel is working at CIA.\n My IP is from Carlos Juan test.". I fixed it using "+.*?" it works, but sometimes it provokes some errors.

Comment: The problem that I told you before about starting with the upper case happens in cases like this "My IP is from Windows Server." It won't get "My". That's why I was using the dot to get all the characters.

Comment: @Codewraith It is not the most efficient, but you might use a pattern to match any char except a punctuation that ends a line. In between match 2 uppercase words, with an optional lowercase part. https://regex101.com/r/Ui5DZ1/1 But even that might have edge cases.

Comment: Sentences like this "Jorge Martel always work." don't get caught because of the first character being an upper case, and I tried to use ? to make it optional, but that's impossible to make it work, once that it will break the rest of the code. That's why my first regex was created to validate only the first character being an upper case. Yeah, this task of mine is hardcore level haha.

Comment: @Codewraith You can make it optional https://regex101.com/r/mW6YKq/1

Comment: Indeed, with this new regex of yours, it is possible. I will review the other problematic cases.

Comment: This one here "The CIA is working with IBM to close this case." It will be considered because the regex uses an undefined quantity of characters between the upper cases (*). The way that I treated it in my previous regex was limiting it to {1,3} lower cases characters, is there another way to validate it?